How to use `Copy` or reborrow on mutable reference in safe rust
Consider the following function :
fn foo(a: &mut usize, fs: Vec<fn(&mut usize)>)
{
    for f in fs {
        f(a);
    }
}

This function compiles in safe rust. However I would like to make this function generic (instead of &mut usize). But I can't figure out which bound to use on the generic argument. Basically I would like a function of the form
fn foo<A>(a: A, fs: Vec<fn(A)>)
where A: ???
{
    for f in fs {
        f(a);
    }
}

I could use the Copy trait (that would enable us to call foo<&T> and foo<usize> ...) however I want this function to compile with mutable reference as well. Of course mutable reference cannot be copied (that would defeat the whole point). So is there a way to do this in a single generic function.
For people that are curious I am working on a Plugin system and I want to be able to register a list of "hooks" with such constraints.

Is there any particular reason you don't want to use fn foo<A>(a: &mut A, fs: Vec<fn(&mut A)>)?

Basically i have a macro called register_hook! that enables to create new hook into my plugin system. In order for it to "modify" states I would like to use mutable reference (in the same way I've written the snippet above). I would like to avoid &RefCell<T> if possible.

The kind of Trait that you want (abstracting over &T, &mut T and Copy) is currently
impossible to create in Rust due to limitations in the borrow checker and
trait system.
I've created a rough sketch of it here, feel free to fiddle with that to gain
an understanding of the limitations you run into there:  https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3be02c507444e285c4a7bc7c4dd641b2
I would suggest just having two versions of foo, one taking a Copy and a second version taking a &mut T,

Thanks for confirming this. I ended up using RefCell for dynamically checked mutability but it is unsightly.

This might not be a very ergonomic approach, and it does incur some overhead due to indirections, but at least I think it solves your problem
fn foo<A>(mut a: A, fs: Vec<fn(&mut A)>)
where
    A: OperateOnType,
{
    for f in fs {
        a.operate(f);
    }
}

trait OperateOnType: Sized {
    fn operate(&mut self, callback: fn(&mut Self)) {
        callback(self)
    }
}

impl<T> OperateOnType for T {}

fn main() {
    let mut x = 3i32;
    let fs = vec![|x: &mut &mut i32| **x = 4, |y: &mut &mut i32| **y = 5];
    foo(&mut x, fs);
    let fs = vec![|x: &mut &i32| println!("{x}"), |y: &mut &i32| {
        println!("{y}")
    }];
    foo(&x, fs);
    let fs = vec![|x: &mut i32| *x += 1, |y: &mut i32| *y = 1];
    foo(x, fs);
}

